# 720kb.datepicker positioning issue in datatable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, datatables, bootstrap-datepicker

I am having a positioning issue of the datepicker in the datatable, when i have a single row in the table the datepicker appears inside the datatable itself and hence its getting the empty space[this is how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spaIG.png)(size of the datepicker) below the datatable row. 
how can I position the datepicker outside the datatable.
Tried using relative position but it does'nt work.

```
 <div ng-if="docData.length > 0" class="searchTable">
        <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" id="docTable"
            class=" row-border hover table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DATE</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in docData | orderBy: $index">
                    <td><datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                            selector="form-control">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input ng-model="doc.newDate" uib-datepicker- 
                        popup="{{format}}"
                                alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" 
                   class="form-control"
                                ng-change="jsonUpdate($index, 
                             doc.requestDate, doc.newRequestDate)"
                                placeholder="Select Date" style="width: 
                           110px" />
                        </div>
                        </datepicker></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```